# Progress bar with downloading using urlopen

Tags: python, url, urllib

My requirement needs me to download a package from a http url and see the progress of the same.

i have below code written

```
import subprocess
from urllib import urlopen


  class MyClass(object):
  '''
  classdocs
  '''

def url_to_download(self):
    url_for_download = "someurl"
    file = "somefilename"
    print "downloading with urllib"

    response = urlopen(url_for_download)
    CHUNK = 16 * 1024
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = response.read(CHUNK)
            cmd = "ls -ltrh" + " " +file + " "+ "|"+ "awk '{print $5}'"
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            (output, err) = p.communicate()
            print "the download progress is" + " " + str(output)
            if not chunk:
                break
            f.write(chunk)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
     download =  MyClass()
      download.number_of_files()
      download.url_to_download()
```

As you could see i have used basically linux commands to see the progress of the download.Is there any way with minimal changes to the codes i can have a horizontal progress details for the download.
thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) has a `reporthook` callback — i.e. you pass a function that `urlretrieve` calls with 3 arguments.

As for progress bar, you can use any [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=progress&submit=search) module a PyPI. See, for example, [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an existing package like **progressbar2**.

[Docs](https://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Installation:

pip install progressbar

Example Usage:

```
import progressbar
import urllib


# Instantiate the progress bar
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()

# Example URLS
urls = ["http://www.stackoverflow.com","http://www.example.com"]

# Iterate through urls and get the html
for url in bar(urls):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    #Do some additional processing here
```